Error fetching favorites: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast
Please can anyone explain what's the issue with this! I am getting this error "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast"
This my code, favorite_service.dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
// import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:e_nusantara/screens/product_details.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../api/auth_service.dart';
import '../models/product_models.dart';

class favoriteService {
  final String? baseUrl = dotenv.env['BASE_URL'];
  final FlutterSecureStorage storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  final AuthService _authService = AuthService();

  Future<String?> getValidToken() async {
    bool isTokenValid = await _authService.checkToken();

    if (isTokenValid) {
      return await storage.read(key: 'accessToken');
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchFavorites() async {
    String? token = await getValidToken();

    if (token == null) {
      throw Exception('Token tidak valid');
    }

    try {
      final res = await http.get(Uri.parse('$baseUrl/favorites'), headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      });

      print("responsenya adalah ${res.body}");

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        if (res.body.isEmpty) {
          return [];
        }

        final List<dynamic> decodedData = jsonDecode(res.body);

        return decodedData.map((item) {
          final productData = item['product'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Product.fromJson(productData);
        }).toList();
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load favorites');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching favorites: $e');
      throw Exception('Failed to load favorites: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<bool> addFavorites(int productId) async {
    String? token = await getValidToken();

    if (token == null) {
      throw Exception('Token tidak valid');
    }
    try {
      final res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('$baseUrl/favorites'),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({'productId': productId}),
      );

      if (res.statusCode == 201) {
        return true;
      } else {
        print('Failed to add favorite, status code: ${res.statusCode}');
        print('Response body: ${res.body}');
        throw Exception('Failed to add Favorite');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print('Error: $err');
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> deleteFavorites(int productId) async {
    String? token = await getValidToken();

    if (token == null) {
      throw Exception('Token tidak valid');
    }

    try {
      final res = await http.delete(
        Uri.parse('$baseUrl/favorites'),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({'productId': productId}),
      );

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        return true;
      } else {
        print('Gagal menambah favorit, kode status: ${res.statusCode}');
        print('Respon body: ${res.body}');
        return false;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw Exception('Failed to delete Favorite: $err');
    }
  }

  Future<bool> isCheckFavorite(int productId) async {
    String? token = await getValidToken();

    if (token == null) {
      throw Exception('Token tidak valid. Silakan login ulang.');
    }

    final url = Uri.parse('$baseUrl/favorites');
    final headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    try {
      final res = await http.get(url, headers: headers);

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        List<dynamic> favorites = json.decode(res.body);
        return favorites.any((favorite) => favorite['product_id'] == productId);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print('Error Not Found: $err');
      return false;
    }
  }
}

and this my code for views, favorite_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import '../api/favorite_service.dart';
import '../models/product_models.dart';
import 'package:e_nusantara/screens/product_details.dart';

class FavoriteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FavoriteScreen({super.key, required});

  @override
  State<FavoriteScreen> createState() => _FavoriteScreenState();
}

class _FavoriteScreenState extends State<FavoriteScreen> {
  late Future<List<dynamic>> _favoritesFuture;
  final favoriteService _favoriteService = favoriteService();
  bool isGridView = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _favoritesFuture = _favoriteService.fetchFavorites();
  }

  void deleteFavorite(int productId) async {
    bool isSuccess = await _favoriteService.deleteFavorites(productId);
    if (isSuccess) {
      setState(() {
        _favoritesFuture = _favoriteService.fetchFavorites();
      });
    }
  }

  Widget buildFavoriteItem(Product item, bool isGridView) {
    return isGridView ? _buildGridItem(item) : _buildListItem(item);
  }

  Widget _buildGridItem(Product item) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => product_details(
                      image: item.images?.first ?? '',
                      title: item.pName ?? '',
                      productId: item.productId ?? 0,
                    )));
      },
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: PageView.builder(
                      itemCount: item.images?.length ?? 0,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final imageUrl = item.images?[index];
                        return Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(imageUrl!),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 8,
                  right: 8,
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => deleteFavorite(item.productId!),
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    item.pName ?? '',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 4),
                  Text(
                    NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'id', symbol: 'Rp')
                        .format(item.price),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 12,
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (item.sale ?? false)
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 6,
                        vertical: 2,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        'On Sale',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 10,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListItem(Product item) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => product_details(
                      image: item.images?.first ?? '',
                      title: item.pName ?? '',
                      productId: item.productId ?? 0,
                    )));
      },
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Image.network(
          item.images?.first ?? '',
          width: 80,
          height: 80,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        title: Text(item.pName ?? ''),
        subtitle: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Brand: ${item.brand ?? ''}'),
            Text(
              'Price: ${NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'id', symbol: 'Rp').format(item.price)}',
            ),
            if (item.sale ?? false)
              const Text(
                'on Sale',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
              ),
          ],
        ),
        trailing: IconButton(
          onPressed: () => deleteFavorite(item.productId!),
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Favorite Products'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isGridView = !isGridView;
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(isGridView ? Icons.view_list : Icons.grid_view),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
        future: _favoritesFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Failed to load Favorite: ${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(child: Text('No Favorite Products'));
          } else {
            final favorites = snapshot.data!;
            return GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: isGridView ? 2 : 1,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                childAspectRatio: isGridView ? 0.8 : 1.2,
              ),
              itemCount: favorites.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return buildFavoriteItem(favorites[index], isGridView);
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


Output the program
Home
Favorite_screen
This code has errors I mentioned in the title already. Here I have a question like how can I pass list value inside the card.

I believe this error can only happen if jsonDecode returns Null which should only happen if res.body == "null"

You have multiple lines like these:
List<dynamic> favorites = json.decode(res.body);

If json.decode returns null then that is the error you get. Your IDE will tell you exactly what line it happened on. You can then debug your code and check why this happened. Maybe there is no body if there are no favorites yet? We don't know. That part is what you have to figure out.
